# Upgrade from mysql 4.1 to mysql 5.5

Tags: upgrade, mysql, mysql4

I was going through upgrade process of mysql server. It is mentioned that to upgrade from 4.1 to 5.5 we need to upgrade step by step like first to 5.0,5.1 ...5.4 and then 5.5.

I have some questions :

- What if we directly upgrade from 4.1 to 5.5. What might get effected? functionality or problem related to upgrading
- Chances to loose data ? Even though I'll take backup using 'mysqldump --all-data-base' option.
- Lets say, I have two database. I'll take only two database backup. I'll install latest version of mysql 5.7 and load two database back. What are chances to loose data or get corrupted ?

I'm curious to know this. If anybody tried? Because I need to do upgrade in live server.

Is there any step by step document which tells exact steps to upgrade from 4.1 to 5.5 in linux server

Comment: you can migrate direct from 5.0 to 5.5 : 
`https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-Migrating_from_MySQL_5.0_to_MySQL_5.5.html`

so you can migrat firtsly to 5.0 then to 5.5

Comment: I guess link is not proper

Comment: The upgrade is only neccessary, if you do not want to do a complete mysqldump and later insert the dump again. If you can afford the downtime you can just create a complete backup, remove the old server version, install a new version and import the previously created dump.

Comment: okay. So I can just uninstall 4.1 and install 5.5+ and load backup.Right?

Comment: @stefun : sorry for the link... i don't know why, but when we open the link /h‌​tml/ become other thing, you just need to retype it correctly with the 2 '/' so retype this '/html/' whereas what your browser had put

Answer (score 0):

Major new features added to MySQL 5.0 and 5.1 that may not work/won't work in 4.x can be located here:

MySQL 5.0 - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html

MySQL 5.1 - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-nutshell.html